# Selecting os after wake on lan using sub-os

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, vnc, ftp, wakeonlan

Recently I had an idea: what if I install a mini os that grub starts by default, that listen for a packet sent by my phone and then it modify the grub configuration files changing the default os to boot?

For example: I wake my pc and I want to take a file from my ubuntu installation via ftp or doing things with Vnc viewer. But the default grub entry is windows 7, then with a linux based mini os can I modify the grub config files, so it boots up ubuntu?

Then, which method can I assume to listen for a packet from my phone?

Thank you all.

Edit: Then this setup it'll be able to reverse thing back

Comment: You could instead have your Ubuntu boot by default. When you then need Windows, you can login to Ubuntu via ssh and tell grub to boot Windows the next time and then reboot. Would that be ok?

Comment: yes but then it can't be undone

Comment: Yes it can. The command `sudo grub-reboot "Windows"` will tell grub to boot into the "Windows" menu entry _just once_ next time it boots. If you then reboot, you'll have Windows. If you then reboot that Windows, you'll be back to Ubuntu because Ubuntu is still the default.

Comment: I know I know, but from windows I can't boot to ubuntu

Comment: No need to explicitely boot _into Ubuntu_ from Windows because Ubuntu is still the default. It is sufficient to just reboot the Windows machine from remote. It will then again restart with Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have a rooted phone or access to some other device, you don't need to boot into another OS, and can instead just have grub query a different device for the default boot option. See my anwer at https://superuser.com/a/1452098/1053751 for more details.